# Unicode expression with SquidGuard

Tags: unicode, squid, arabic

I'm using SquidGuard 1.4 with Squid3, it worked like charm and I can block adult site with expression DB file contain English pattern.

```
(^|[-\?+=/_])(bondage|boobs?|busty?|hardcore|porno?|sex|xxx+)([-\?+=/_]|$)
```

My question is how can I filter Arabic adult sites using Unicode expression to block words like "سكس" or whatever?